# Find and Replace Everything Before a String of Text

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, sed, find, replace

I have a large list of IP addresses (most are IPv4, but a few are IPv6), followed by a space and then a domain name, followed by another space and the same domain name with "www." in front of it. Each instance is on it's own line. The list looks like this (*but is much larger*):

```
23.212.109.137 at.ask.com www.at.ask.com
216.58.206.74 maps.googleapis.com www.maps.googleapis.com
2400:cb00:2048:1::6812:32a5 litscape.com www.litscape.com
104.16.244.35 loc.gov www.loc.gov
216.70.104.235 mbu.edu www.mbu.edu
```

I would like to know two find and replace commands; each to generate another text file after the last.

1) The first command should find and replace *everything* before the "www." with "http://" so that the lines of the second text file will look like this:

```
http://www.at.ask.com
http://www.maps.googleapis.com
http://www.litscape.com
http://www.loc.gov
http://www.mbu.edu
```

2) The second command should find and replace all instances of "http://www." in the second text file so that the lines of the third text file will look like this:

```
at.ask.com
maps.googleapis.com
litscape.com
loc.gov
mbu.edu
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single ***awk*** command:

```
awk '{ print $2 > "domains.txt"; print "http://"$3 > "domains_http.txt" }' file
```

---

Results:

```
> cat domains_http.txt 
http://www.at.ask.com
http://www.maps.googleapis.com
http://www.litscape.com
http://www.loc.gov
http://www.mbu.edu
```

---

```
> cat domains.txt 
at.ask.com
maps.googleapis.com
litscape.com
loc.gov
mbu.edu
```

Answer (score 1):

The second thing is easiest:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 2 file.in
```

This uses `cut` with a space as delimiter and cuts out the second column.

With `awk` it would be easy to do both tasks:

```
$ awk '{ print $2 }' file.in
```

That does essentially the same as the `cut` command.

```
$ awk '{ print "http://" $3 }' file.in
```

That takes the third column and prepends `http://` to it before outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed 's#.*\(www.*\)#http://\1#' source_file > dest_file1
sed 's#.*www\.\(.*\)#\1#' dest_file1 > dest_file2
```

Explanation:

For the first requirement, start grouping everything from `www`, and replace everything that doesn't fall into this group with `http://`. Similar for the second file as well, but now start grouping from after `www.`

Note that if you want *commands* to do these jobs, you can always alias these into custom commands.